# Need android device setting screen off timeout listener

Tags: android, timeout, screen

I need / want to add device setting screen off timeout listener to update my switch with latest time which user select in setting preferences of the device.

Code i tried:

```
  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Pref changes");
        }
    };
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 0);
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

I tried this but seems like listener is only work for specific context(appContext in my case)

can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old-ish question, but since I recently found out how to do this I thought I'd post my answer in case others come across this question.

In following example, "context" is your Activity or Service...

```
int displayTimeout;

ContentObserver settingsContentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    try {
        int checkDisplayTimeout = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT);
        if (checkDisplayTimeout != displayTimeout) {
            // the DisplayTimeout has changed
            displayTimeout = checkDisplayTimeout;
        }
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // The SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT setting didn't change 'cause it doesn't exist
    }
}};
```

To get it to start listening, use

```
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, settingsContentObserver);
```

By using the `android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI`, this ContentObserver should respond to many (but not all) of the Settings changes.

Make sure you turn it off when you're done listening.

```
context.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(settingsContentObserver);
```